# Reorder an array from it's default order

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that comes in this way since it's generated this way, and it's a heck of a task to change the way it's generated. This is part of it, there loads more.

```
$name['Age'] = '25';
$name['Location'] = 'Seattle';
$name['Last'] = 'Gates';
$name['First'] = 'Bill';

print_r($name);
```

How can I change it's order to something like below once it's generated?

```
$name['First'] = 'Bill';
$name['Last'] = 'Gates';
$name['Age'] = '25';
$name['Location'] = 'Seattle';

print_r($name);
```

Comment: Why does it matter what order the associative keys are in...?

Comment: I think he is probable doing some for to read the array and the order is not like he want. So, as you dont have any pattern to the order you have, you will have to have an array with the keys on the order that you want (create your pattern) then you will have to manually change the positions in your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a function that lets you reorder the associative array by keys according to your own criteria. It's called [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php):

```
$key_order = array_flip(['First', 'Last', 'Age', 'Location']);
uksort($name, function($key1, $key2) {
  return $key_order[$key1] - $key_order[$key2];
});

print_r($name);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/57771).

---

Having said all that, I can't help wondering ain't you need something different instead: changing the order of *output* of your array only. For example:

```
$output_order = ['First', 'Last', 'Age', 'Location'];
foreach ($output_order as $key) {
  echo $key, ' => ', $name[$key], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: The reason I need it reordered is because I use this array in a str_replace function and need it to match the other array.